# How to handle socket disconnects in Dart?

Tags: sockets, dart

I'm using Dart 1.8.5 on server.
I want to implement TCP Socket Server that listens to incoming connections, sends some data to every client and stops to generate data when client disconnects.

Here is the sample code

```dart
void main() {
  ServerSocket.bind(
      InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4,
      9000).then((ServerSocket server) {
    runZoned(() {
      server.listen(handleClient);
    }, onError: (e) {
      print('Server error: $e');
    });
  });
}

void handleClient(Socket client) {
  client.done.then((_) {
    print('Stop sending');
  });
  print('Send data');
}
```

This code accepts connections and prints "Send data". But it will never print "Stop sending" even if client was gone.

The question is: how to catch client disconnect in listener?

Comment: To me this looks like a bug. Please create an issue at http://dartbug.com

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22583

Comment: You can see example in my answer. It displays `Stop sending` and in detals expains the problem that found in the Dart SDK.

Answer (score 4):

A Socket is bidirectional, i.e. it has an input stream and an output sink. The Future returned by done is called when the output sink is closed by calling [Socket.close()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Socket#id_close).

If you want to be notified when the input stream closes try using [Socket.drain()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Socket#id_drain) instead.

See the example below. You can test it with telnet. When you connect to the server it will send the string "Send." every second. When you close telnet (ctrl-], and then type close). The server will print "Stop.".

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void handleClient(Socket socket) {

  // Send a string to the client every second.
  var timer = new Timer.periodic(
      new Duration(seconds: 1), 
      (_) => socket.writeln('Send.'));

  // Wait for the client to disconnect, stop the timer, and close the
  // output sink of the socket.
  socket.drain().then((_) {
    print('Stop.');    
    timer.cancel();
    socket.close();
  });
}

void main() {
  ServerSocket.bind(
      InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4,
      9000).then((ServerSocket server) {
    runZoned(() {
      server.listen(handleClient);
    }, onError: (e) {
      print('Server error: $e');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your answer. I am sending query and after I get query I need to close the socket. how do I do that?

Comment: I'm getting `Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.` when I try to drain the socket