# How to close dart socket based on the for data loop?

Tags: sockets, dart

Below code works very fast if I use socket.close inside the for loop.
But if I do I cannot get long data. I need to use await for (var data in socket) but when can I understand no more data so I can close the socket.

How to close dart socket based on the for data loop?

```
String reply;

var socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.1.88’, 8080);
socket.write(‘TEST\r\n’);

await for (var data in socket) {
    reply = await new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
    print("reply: $reply");


     //*** if I use “socket.close” here I can’t get long data
     //*** otherwise I get data very fast
     //socket.close  
}
```

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745138/how-to-handle-socket-disconnects-in-dart see also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22583

Comment: I saw all the info, and thanks again. But seems I cannot get correct answer. If you have clear example for this I will appreciate the link. Thanks again

Comment: I can't use the socket.drain(). My flutter app simply sends query to socket and expect the data. if no more data than socket must close the connection. how do I do that?

Comment: Then you must wait until you have all the expected data before you call `socket.close()`

Comment: I used an await socket.close but it take ages to even get simple data. so I move socket.close outside for loop and it takes ages to close he socket. So it seems I need to while loop or something...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you have https://v1-dartlang-org.firebaseapp.com/dart-vm/dart-by-example#sockets documentation for Dart 2

Comment: Also can you send me to new link for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654952/how-to-respond-to-socket-on-dart

Comment: The code from Dart 1 should work the same in Dart 2.

Comment: cannot find utf8 in socket.transform(utf8.decoder)

Comment: Import `dart:convert`

Comment: thanks, one last question how to close socket from client